# My new PRNG (PaulssonSponge) with dieharder tests

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

I run an open source project implementing some RipeMD and SHA hashes, one day I got nerdy and threw together my own Sponge function. I have now tested it with the dieharder 3.31.1 test suite. Is it acceptable to use as an PRNG for cryptography? This is the results:

```
> dieharder -a -f IdeaProjects/angelos-project-crypt/sponge.bin 
#=============================================================================#
#            dieharder version 3.31.1 Copyright 2003 Robert G. Brown          #
#=============================================================================#
   rng_name    |           filename             |rands/second|
        mt19937|IdeaProjects/angelos-project-crypt/sponge.bin|  1.54e+08  |
#=============================================================================#
        test_name   |ntup| tsamples |psamples|  p-value |Assessment
#=============================================================================#
   diehard_birthdays|   0|       100|     100|0.29741314|  PASSED  
      diehard_operm5|   0|   1000000|     100|0.90355675|  PASSED  
  diehard_rank_32x32|   0|     40000|     100|0.09680105|  PASSED  
    diehard_rank_6x8|   0|    100000|     100|0.88497509|  PASSED  
   diehard_bitstream|   0|   2097152|     100|0.51462962|  PASSED  
        diehard_opso|   0|   2097152|     100|0.89314254|  PASSED  
        diehard_oqso|   0|   2097152|     100|0.53780624|  PASSED  
         diehard_dna|   0|   2097152|     100|0.36760105|  PASSED  
diehard_count_1s_str|   0|    256000|     100|0.69366264|  PASSED  
diehard_count_1s_byt|   0|    256000|     100|0.66152108|  PASSED  
 diehard_parking_lot|   0|     12000|     100|0.32092307|  PASSED  
    diehard_2dsphere|   2|      8000|     100|0.71844281|  PASSED  
    diehard_3dsphere|   3|      4000|     100|0.37909585|  PASSED  
     diehard_squeeze|   0|    100000|     100|0.20023243|  PASSED  
        diehard_sums|   0|       100|     100|0.62144443|  PASSED  
        diehard_runs|   0|    100000|     100|0.77236221|  PASSED  
        diehard_runs|   0|    100000|     100|0.94063879|  PASSED  
       diehard_craps|   0|    200000|     100|0.19105781|  PASSED  
       diehard_craps|   0|    200000|     100|0.92211531|  PASSED  
 marsaglia_tsang_gcd|   0|  10000000|     100|0.79178970|  PASSED  
 marsaglia_tsang_gcd|   0|  10000000|     100|0.03659520|  PASSED  
         sts_monobit|   1|    100000|     100|0.83442684|  PASSED  
            sts_runs|   2|    100000|     100|0.09095137|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   1|    100000|     100|0.40236648|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   2|    100000|     100|0.87652788|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   3|    100000|     100|0.49927519|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   3|    100000|     100|0.77902061|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   4|    100000|     100|0.55240161|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   4|    100000|     100|0.73160126|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   5|    100000|     100|0.87317097|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   5|    100000|     100|0.28445531|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   6|    100000|     100|0.76610989|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   6|    100000|     100|0.03522221|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   7|    100000|     100|0.58197692|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   7|    100000|     100|0.53187944|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   8|    100000|     100|0.83115449|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   8|    100000|     100|0.64294087|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   9|    100000|     100|0.94770237|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|   9|    100000|     100|0.56747611|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  10|    100000|     100|0.94722485|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  10|    100000|     100|0.34604921|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  11|    100000|     100|0.71566033|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  11|    100000|     100|0.99317603|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  12|    100000|     100|0.99568394|   WEAK   
          sts_serial|  12|    100000|     100|0.84314212|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  13|    100000|     100|0.67188110|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  13|    100000|     100|0.33426603|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  14|    100000|     100|0.55951121|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  14|    100000|     100|0.61895131|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  15|    100000|     100|0.63782432|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  15|    100000|     100|0.60490933|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  16|    100000|     100|0.24365935|  PASSED  
          sts_serial|  16|    100000|     100|0.01825019|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|   1|    100000|     100|0.25511084|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|   2|    100000|     100|0.78160123|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|   3|    100000|     100|0.86346874|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|   4|    100000|     100|0.21934989|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|   5|    100000|     100|0.06051574|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|   6|    100000|     100|0.69356798|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|   7|    100000|     100|0.25615210|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|   8|    100000|     100|0.99313684|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|   9|    100000|     100|0.12193544|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|  10|    100000|     100|0.40998421|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|  11|    100000|     100|0.79477040|  PASSED  
         rgb_bitdist|  12|    100000|     100|0.47304485|  PASSED  
rgb_minimum_distance|   2|     10000|    1000|0.95942258|  PASSED  
rgb_minimum_distance|   3|     10000|    1000|0.52655847|  PASSED  
rgb_minimum_distance|   4|     10000|    1000|0.32272802|  PASSED  
rgb_minimum_distance|   5|     10000|    1000|0.31016307|  PASSED  
    rgb_permutations|   2|    100000|     100|0.25521657|  PASSED  
    rgb_permutations|   3|    100000|     100|0.39659659|  PASSED  
    rgb_permutations|   4|    100000|     100|0.58523664|  PASSED  
    rgb_permutations|   5|    100000|     100|0.99143517|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   0|   1000000|     100|0.92651784|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   1|   1000000|     100|0.87079304|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   2|   1000000|     100|0.22619148|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   3|   1000000|     100|0.34505477|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   4|   1000000|     100|0.18581204|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   5|   1000000|     100|0.60116499|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   6|   1000000|     100|0.98932222|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   7|   1000000|     100|0.04374118|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   8|   1000000|     100|0.33544339|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|   9|   1000000|     100|0.90441273|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  10|   1000000|     100|0.22257880|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  11|   1000000|     100|0.66960544|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  12|   1000000|     100|0.27262357|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  13|   1000000|     100|0.52498198|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  14|   1000000|     100|0.37751496|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  15|   1000000|     100|0.76524735|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  16|   1000000|     100|0.87963412|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  17|   1000000|     100|0.78610111|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  18|   1000000|     100|0.65942432|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  19|   1000000|     100|0.92103411|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  20|   1000000|     100|0.20000362|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  21|   1000000|     100|0.63948529|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  22|   1000000|     100|0.82132269|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  23|   1000000|     100|0.35830568|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  24|   1000000|     100|0.13945365|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  25|   1000000|     100|0.29604927|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  26|   1000000|     100|0.66900002|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  27|   1000000|     100|0.35142717|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  28|   1000000|     100|0.97404828|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  29|   1000000|     100|0.40686983|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  30|   1000000|     100|0.70110560|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  31|   1000000|     100|0.94398652|  PASSED  
      rgb_lagged_sum|  32|   1000000|     100|0.03111049|  PASSED  
     rgb_kstest_test|   0|     10000|    1000|0.07793768|  PASSED  
     dab_bytedistrib|   0|  51200000|       1|0.66122968|  PASSED  
             dab_dct| 256|     50000|       1|0.06893023|  PASSED  
Preparing to run test 207.  ntuple = 0
        dab_filltree|  32|  15000000|       1|0.53679563|  PASSED  
        dab_filltree|  32|  15000000|       1|0.64155528|  PASSED  
Preparing to run test 208.  ntuple = 0
       dab_filltree2|   0|   5000000|       1|0.25169708|  PASSED  
       dab_filltree2|   1|   5000000|       1|0.82549244|  PASSED  
Preparing to run test 209.  ntuple = 0
        dab_monobit2|  12|  65000000|       1|0.51036954|  PASSED
```

Comment: Validating a PRNG for cryptographic use based on result of statistical tests of it's output is an erroneous design methodology (in a nutshell: because statistical tests make no use of the internal structure of the generator, that they are not even given; when the opposite assumption is made in attacks on PRNG in cryptography, since [Kerckhoffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)). That many have used that design methodology does not make it less wrong. While the sponge structure is a sound framework, there are still possible pitfalls, e.g. in the sponge design itself.

Comment: Well, I am not a mathematician, so presumably there could be pitfalls, do you know where to go from here

Answer (score 1):

My code for the Sponge can be found in my repository back in time, about a week. [Here](https://github.com/angelos-project/angelos-project-crypt/tree/9783e86002029397f8f6fb57e6feacc5b9d45f2c/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/angproj/crypt/kp)

The Sponge is in the file PaulssonSponge.kt, then an abstract class in AbstractPaulssonSponge.kt and finally an application in PaulssonHash.kt

A unit test can be found [here](https://github.com/angelos-project/angelos-project-crypt/blob/9783e86002029397f8f6fb57e6feacc5b9d45f2c/src/jvmVectorTest/kotlin/crypt/kp/PaulssonHashTest.kt).

The binary data was generated from the squeeze function and stored in a not checked in UnitTest, I have it on my Linux machine. I compared the dieharder with the result from Linux /dev/urandom which had two weaknesses, my Sponge had one weakness, so needed to ask questions. Just a nerdy side project.

Comment: 1.)   What drove the decision to construct the sponge function in terms of whole bytes/longs, rather than individual bits as Keccak does? 2.)   Where do the initialisation constants  for `entropyState` come from?  Just wonderin'.

Comment: 1) Actually I was implementing keccak for private use, then I had seen so many permutation functions from Sha1, Sha2 and RipeMD, so I got the idea to experiment with different similar things, technically the Sponge is shuffled according to a pattern, the words are rotated based on the first 16 primes and then there is an Invert and every second Negate which I guess generates a bunch of entropy by itself.

Comment: 2)`entropyState` could actually be empty (zeros), I did first set them to high 64-bit primes generated with OpenSSL, I then took the values after 10 000 000 000 iterations of MonteCarlo testing, so they are just a later state of the early primes I used.

Comment: I perused your source code but couldn't see any non linear components. Do you also include some form of non linearity like a LFSR?

Comment: I had to read up on LFSR and NLFSR I'm not sure whether there is any of those but there is a bunch of XOR and rotateLeft. The magic happens in the `cycle` function. By the way I visited your website, very interesting topic.